# topology of left half-open intervals

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

i messed up an exam yesterday. given

$$\mathcal{B}:=\{(a,b]:a,b \in\mathbb{R}, a \le b\},$$

i was able to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is the base of a topology $\mathcal{T}$, and that $\mathcal{T}$ is finer than the standard topology. however, i couldn't find a countable dense subset in $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T})$ :S i thought about $\mathbb{Q}$, but is $\mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{T}$? how to show that there is no countable base for $\mathcal{T}$?

i'm just curious, and a bit afraid that there is a simple answer to this :S

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is not open in this topology, but that’s irrelevant to the question of whether it’s dense in the space. Is it true that every member of $\mathscr{B}$ contains a rational number?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't open in the usual topology either, but that doesn't keep it from being dense there.

Comment: oh :S i see, that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: To show that the space has no countable base, let $\mathscr{B}$ be any base for $\mathscr{T}$, and note that for each $x\in\Bbb R$ there must be some $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq(x-1,x]$. Then show that if $x\ne y$, then $B_x\ne B_y$.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the Sorgenfrey line.Although it's usually given in reverse ,with the base  of intervals $[a,b)$ .(Not the same space but its mirror image, homeomorphic to it by the function $f(x)=-x$.) I will stick to your def'n.Let $C$ be a base. For each real $r$ there exists $C_r\in C$ such that $r\in C_r\subset (r-1,r]$ because $(r-1,r]$ is a nbhd of $r$ and $C$ is a base. With respect to the usual order on the reals we have $\max (C_r)=r$ . So $C_r\ne C_s$ when $r\ne s$..Since $\{C_r :r\in R\}\subset C$ the cardinal of $C$ is at least the cardinal of the reals.....(Remark ; Any open set of the Sorgenfrey line is a union of countably many half-open intervals, so the set of ALL Sorgenfrey-open sets has the same cardinal as the set of  reals.)